# figuring out how many blocks and threads for a cuda kernel, and how to use them

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have been trying to figure out how to make what I thought would be a simple kernel to take the average of the values in a 2d matrix, but I am having some issues getting my thought process straight on it.

According to my deviceQuery output, my GPU has 16MP, 32cores/mp, blocks max is 1024x1024x64 and I have a max threads/block=1024.

So, I am working on processings some large images. Maybe 5000px x 3500px or something like that. One of my kernels is taking an average of some values across all pixels in the image.

The existing code has the images stored as a 2D array [rows][cols]. So that kernel, in C,  looks like you'd expect, wtih a loop over rows, and a loop over cols, with the calculation in the middle.

So how do I set up the dimension calculation portion of this code in CUDA? I have looked at the reduction code int he SDK, but that is for a single dimension array. It doesnt have any mention of how to set up number of blocks and threads for when you have soemthing 2D.

I am thinking I'd actually need to set it up like so, and this is where I'd like someone to chime in and help:

```
num_threads=1024;
blocksX = num_cols/sqrt(num_threads);
blocksY = num_rows/sqrt(num_threads);
num_blocks = (num_rows*num_cols)/(blocksX*blocksY);

dim3 dimBlock(blocksX, blocksY, 1);
dim3 dimGrid(num_blocks, 1, 1);
```

Does this seem to make sense for the setup?

And then in the kernel, to work on a particular row or column, i'd have to use

rowidx = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadId.x
colidx = (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y)+threadId.y

At least I think that would work for getting a row and column.

How would I then access that particular row r and column c in the kernel? In the cuda programming guide I found the following code:

```
// Host code int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr; size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch, width * sizeof(float), height);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPtr, pitch, width, height);
// Device code __global__ void MyKernel(float* devPtr, size_t pitch, int width, int height)
{
for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r)
{
float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c)
{
float element = row[c];
}
}
}
```

Which looks similar to how you'd use malloc in C to declare a 2D array, but it doesnt have any mention of accessing that array in your own kernel. I guess in my code, I will use that cudaMallocPitch call, and then perform a memcpy to get my data into the 2D array on the device?

Any tips appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I figured this question in the following fashion.

```
// Grid and block size
const dim3 blockSize(16,16,1);
const dim3 gridSize(numRows, numCols, 1); 
// kernel call
rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols
```

gridsize  = Number of Block 
blocksize = Threads per Block

Here is the corresponding kernel

```
__global__ void rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4* const rgbaImage,
                       unsigned char* const greyImage,
                       int numRows, int numCols)
{ 
    int idx = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * numRows;
    uchar4 pixel     = rgbaImage[idx]; 
    float  intensity = 0.299f * pixel.x + 0.587f * pixel.y + 0.114f * pixel.z;  
    greyImage[idx]   = static_cast<unsigned char>(intensity);   
}
```

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

For performance applications like this you need to store 2D matrix information as a single array in memory. So if you have an M x N matrix then you can store it in a single array of length M*N.

So if you want to store the 2x2 matrix

```
(1 , 2)
(3 , 4)
```

Then you create a single array an initialize the elements at row i, and column j using the following.

```
int rows=2;
int cols=2;
float* matrix = malloc(sizeof(float)*rows*cols);
matrix[i*cols+j]=yourValue;
//element 0,0
matrix[0*cols+0]=1.0;
//element 0,1
matrix[0*cols+1]=2.0;
//element 1,0
matrix[1*cols+0]=3.0;
//element 1,1
matrix[1*cols+1]=4.0;
```

This way of taking an 2D array and storing it a single continuous piece of memory in this way is called storing data in Row-major order. See Wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Once you change the layout of your data to this kind of format you can use the reduction that was shown in the SDK and your code should be a lot faster as you will be able to do more coalesced reads in the GPU kernel code.

Comment: I agree this is the simplest (and likely most efficient) way to address this problem. My only concern is precision: if you are doing a sum reduction of very large images with high-precision pixels, then you may run out of bits, so ensure you use a large enough datatype. Alternatively, you could modify the reduction to compute a running average rather than a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a short snippet with a simple kernel from my own code.  The float pointers are all device pointers.  Hope this is helpful.

Defines and help functions:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

int iDivUp(int a, int b){
    return (a % b != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b);
}
```

Block size calculation:

```
dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
dim3 dimGridProj(iDivUp(width,BLOCK_SIZE), iDivUp(height,BLOCK_SIZE));
```

Host call:

```
calc_residual<<<dimGridProj, dimBlock>>>(d_image1, d_proj1, d_raynorm1, d_resid1, width, height);
```

Kernel:

```
__global__ void calc_residual(float *d_imagep, float *d_projp, float *d_raysump, float *d_residualp, int width, int height)
{
    int iy = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
if (iy >= height) {
    return;
}
int ix = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
if (ix >= width) {
    return;
}
int idx = iy * width + ix;
float raysumv = d_raysump[idx];
if (raysumv > 0.001) {
    d_residualp[idx] = (d_projp[idx]-d_imagep[idx])/raysumv;
} 
else{
    d_residualp[idx] = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: If I understand what iDivUP is doing, you can simplify the logic a bit thanks to integer truncation: return (a+b-1)/b;